# Как получить ID пользователя телеграм бота, вне функции Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Я знаю как получить ID юзера обычным образом:

```
async def start(message: types.Message):
   await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Вот твой айди {message.from_user.id}')
```

Но вопрос, **можно ли узнать id вне функции** `async def start(message: types.Message)`?

Answer (score 0):

узнать можно с помощью message.from_user.id в любом хендлере, который принимает message
А если хендлер принимает callback_query, то он получается с помощью callback_query.from_user.id
Если нужно получить вне хендлера, придется при старте сохранять id, и вытаскивать его при надобности,